# Read temperature, humdity, etc from grib2 files with EECodes in python3

Tags: python-3.x, weather, grib

I am trying to use EECodes in python to get various weather information, such as temperature, humidity, etc out of grib2 files.  I am using the GFS files.  I would like to be able to extract the data as (lat,lon,alt,$data_point), and as a 2d array for each altitude.

I have tried the example programs located here: https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC/grib_iterator_bitmap

I can't figure out what I am looking in the output of that program.  When I load the messages using their keys, it is not obvious how to make a grid.  When I load the grid, the data doesn't have labels I understand.

Answer (score 2):

@craeft have a look to https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib. `cfgrib` is the new standard for python and grib file handling. It is easy to install and easy to access files. Please install the latest version because it supports GFS files.

Comment: I can't get it to install.  It looks like the ecCodes in conda forge is not up to date?

Comment: The best way would be to use apt manager, but it is only available for ubuntu distributions. Otherwise you have to share your error message then I can help you again.

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work, but it won't open GFS files properly.  Check out this link: https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib/issues/2 .  I can't get a list of variables, and I can't get data from multiple layers.